# How to give a mesh collider gravity 5.0

Tags: unity, mesh, rigidbody, meshcollider

I was trying to make a simulation of an object that needs gravity to work, a hydraulic movement-assistance system for disabled people. All parts are aligned properly, all objects have mesh colliders and rigidbodies, but still gravity does not affect the limb and it floats in the air. How can I make gravity affect it? [image: As you can see, the small cube with rigid body falls, but the leg does not]

Comment: anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have u assigned rigid body?

Comment: yes, I have, but the unity editor prompted me to make it kinematic, and it wont move, if I uncheck kinematic, the object will dissapear

Comment: If kinematic is enabled, the object will not be driven by the physics engine, and can only be manipulated by its Transform.

Comment: provide detail about your problem

Comment: well... I cannot play the scene unless the rigidbodies are kinematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that rigid-body kinematic property is true then you should need to remember that

> It ignores the gravity if isKinematic == true.

If this is not the case then, that leaves three options.

1. it's colliding with something and can't fall.
2. it's so big that you can hardly see it move.
3. the visible object isn't the object being affected by gravity.([ref](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gravity-not-working-on-rigidbody.48036/))

As you mention in comments how to move object without physics then you can use different solutions like
1. using [translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)
2. [MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) - movement toward specific target
3. [by changing position](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/unity3d-moving-an-object-with-keyboard-input/)

Comment: ok, I know a kinematic object dosent move, but it has to be kinematic, it is a mesh collider

Comment: i didn't say kinematic object doesn't move you can move it absolutely! but object will not be driven by physics engine

Comment: then how do I make it move

Comment: if you want make movement you can use translate. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: if you want to make movement toward specific target then, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Comment: you can also do movement by changing the object position but it is not correct approach anyhow you can use it. http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/unity3d-moving-an-object-with-keyboard-input/

Comment: hope that answer have done!

Comment: thanks!, I'll be sure to give you some rep and check ur answer!(please add those links into ur answer)

Comment: glad that it helped:)